# how to add username and password to Selenium Grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I have installed the Docker image [selenium/standalone-chrome](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome) in an Azure Container Instance and I can access it from the public IP as I want, but I would like to secure it with a username and a password.
I think the I have to add vnet to my Azure setup to secure it.

but I would like to hear if some of you knows a command in the image, that I could call to add a username and password to the Selenium Grid?